# Why fallback intent is not working in api.ai?

Tags: dialogflow-es

When the user types some random words that doesn't match to any intent, my agent instead of recognizing it as a fall back intent, categorizes it as some particular intent.
And astonishing fact is that such random words get matched as a particular entity. and trust me such words random garbage words are not defined in my entity.
I am unable to find solution for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Check whether "Default Fallback intent" is available in your list of intents or enabled in your agent.

Check all your training examples in your intents properly.

For more Info follow this link
https://docs.api.ai/docs/concept-intents#fallback-intent